# Using PHP variable inside do_shortcode() for WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

first - sorry about the title, not sure exactly how to name what I need.

Here's what I'd like to do:

1) Get the post ID
2) Get the Custom Field from said post id
3) Display shortcode with the custom field's value

Here's what I have:

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo get_post_meta($postid, 'id-del-instructor', true);
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

With this, I am able to get and display the shortcode's value - although I need to store it for later use rather than display it.

Then, I found this to display the shortcode with PHP:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[awsmteam id="XXX"]"); ?>
```

I have tried combining these two codes but every time it breaks my site.

Basically, where it says XXX, I need the value from the shortcode. It's probably something simple to achieve but I have been looping around and can't get my head around it.

Help? :) Thanks so much!

RESOLVED with this code - thanks @Alon Eitan:

```
<?php
    global $wp_query;
    $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
    $meta =  get_post_meta($postid, 'id-del-instructor', true);
    wp_reset_query();
    echo do_shortcode('[awsmteam id="' . $meta . '"]');
?>
```

Comment: don't think it does

Comment: So I don't understand. Are you trying to do the following: `<?php echo do_shortcode('[awsmteam id="' . $wp_query->post->ID .  '"]'); ?>` ?

Comment: seems you're on the right path! inside the id="" i need to display the value of the shortcode inside the post->ID. Does this make sense?

Comment: thanks brother, I was able to resolve it with your suggestion!!!! THANKS SO MUCH (edited the code on the post itself so it's visible for all!)

Comment: Glad to help :) Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing this inside a page template, you could simply do.

```
    $meta =  get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'id-del-instructor', true);
    echo do_shortcode('[awsmteam id="' . $meta . '"]');
```

rather than call the global $wp_query and go through those other steps.